# Python Requests Session object - something wrong with session variables so authentication happens each request

Tags: python, authentication, session, python-requests

I am working on a script to make repeated API calls to a known URL that has HTTPDigestAuthentication applied to it. Using a requests.Session object I am able to successfully log into the API URL and execute the call. What I am seeing when I look at the headers of subsequent calls in the same session would indicate that the session object is re-authenticating each time a call is made. I also notice that the 'nc' attribute remains at 1 and never seems to increment for subsequent calls. My code is simple and looks like this:

```
import sys
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

uri = "http://{}/cgi-bin/"
Config = "configManager.cgi"
opt = {'action':'someAction',
       'name':'someActionName'}

def activate(URL,Port,usr,pwd):
    with Session() as s:
        s.auth = HTTPDigestAuth(usr,pwd)
        s.params = opt
        s.stream = False
        req = Request("GET", uri.format(URL + ":" + Port) + Config)
        prepped = s.prepare_request(req)
        res = s.send(prepped)
        print('__________________________')
        print('Request made...')
        print('Result = ' + str(res.status_code))
        print('Result Length = ' + str(len(res.text)))
        print('__________________________')
        print('Request Headers:')
        print(res.request.headers)
        print('__________________________')
##        print('Request Result Text / Body:')
##        print(res.text)        
        prepped = s.prepare_request(req)  ##second call to API
        res = s.send(prepped)
        print('__________________________')
        print('Second call in same session')
        print('Result = ' + str(res.status_code))
        print('Result Length = ' + str(len(res.text)))
        print('__________________________')
        print('Request Headers:')
        print(res.request.headers)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    URL = sys.argv[1]
    Port = sys.argv[2]
    usr = sys.argv[3]
    pwd = sys.argv[4]
    activate(URL,Port,usr,pwd)
```

The output of the two calls looks like this:

```
__________________________
Request made...
Result = 200
Result Length = 12073
__________________________
Request Headers:
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'Digest username="*****", realm="Login to 0c84034edf5ce245f4e5a78dcb574664", nonce="2105242886", uri="/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=someAction&name=someActionName", response="68f222dfec55b8d89213eef06c381fc7", opaque="624583b8589f4553521761829dfffe984695b2a8", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="3c824855dbf2f2ab"'}
__________________________
__________________________
Second call in same session
Result = 200
Result Length = 12073
__________________________
Request Headers:
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'Digest username="*****", realm="Login to 0c84034edf5ce245f4e5a78dcb574664", nonce="1581905242", uri="/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=someAction&name=someActionName", response="61946d8d22f9532299aebe3a3f6525db", opaque="624583b8589f4553521761829dfffe984695b2a8", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="e66fd0764906eff2"'}
```

You can see that in each call there is a different nonce and subsequently the other authorisation factors have also been renewed between calls. The nc value should normally indicate 1 for the first call, 2 for the second and so on incrementing until either the session expires - which requires a new authentication - or the last call is made and the session terminated.

How am I able to maintain the session authentication throughout and make multiple calls without the need for re-authentication? I must be missing something simple.

PS: As I understand it the calls must all be prepared, and they will all be 'GET' calls. Maybe there is a way to simplify this bit too. Not sure if it matters in the end as long as the call is made successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The docs have a lot of info on this and I appear to be following them correctly... just doesn't look like the outcome I expected to see.

Cheers

The Frog

Comment: *Does* the server return a session token of any kind…?

Comment: The authentication method is RFC2617 and the 'token' per-se is calculated by the client. It is a kind of handshake with the server where the initial communication results in the servers generation of a number of values. The client then performs a series of calculations to create the response. The server then issues a '200' if the call is authenticated. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

So yes there is a sort of token, however it is handled by the client once the server has handed over the authentication calculation values.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood that you were surprised that the authentication is repeated with every request. But you're just surprised by the `nc` value within that expected authentication. If you formatted those headers so they're more readable, that might help avoid that misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. Sorry for the level of detail I have here.

In a nutshell you understand the scenario. The digest authentication should be recalculated on the client side for any subsequent calls and 'incremented' (so to speak) until the server gives a '401', at which point the cycle can start again.

Comment: Maybe requests isn't the right tool for this task. Perhaps I need to use something less abstracted and build the right functionality into it. At the moment it works, it's just inefficient and adding both network traffic and slowing the server down. I might end up placing several hundred calls to a specific server, in order, and then repeating the process on hundreds of other servers. Getting the behaviour right will yield performance and reliability dividends in the long run.